# Loading Values From An Array In Assembly Language

Tags: arrays, assembly, arm, microcontroller, keil

I am working on one of the simple codes assigned for a ARM microprocessor course I'm taking. I am having a slight issue with getting my code to load a value of an array to compare using Keil. The program is supposed to compare 5 numbers and then store values if the comparison is true. When I run my program it will not load array values that I declared. My professor isn't much help either and doesn't seem to know why it's not working properly.

Here's what I have done so far. I also think my PUSH is wrong but I can probably figure that out after I at least get the array to load. I should be pushing those values onto the stack but I am pretty sure I'm just loading values in registers instead.

```
    AREA    main, CODE, READONLY
    EXPORT __main 
    ENTRY

__main   PROC
MOVS r5, #0
LDR r0, =NUMB
loop1
LDR r1, [r0]
CMP r5, #5
BEQ stop

loop
CMP r1, #10
BLT low10
CMP r1, #100
BLT mid
CMP r1, #255
BLT high100

low10
PUSH {r2}
MOVS r2, #2
ADDS r5, #1
B loop1

mid
PUSH {r3}
MOVS r3, #0
ADDS r5, #1
B loop1

high100
PUSH {r4}
MOVS r4, #1
ADDS r5, #1
B loop1

stop B stop

    ENDP    

    AREA myDATA, DATA, READWRITE 
    ALIGN
NUMB    DCD 1,11,111,11,1
        END
```

Comment: describe your algorithm verbally, what do you mean by compare the five values, etc?  just describe what it has to do then we can see what your code is actually doing relative to that.

Comment: _"When I run my program it will not load array values that I declared"_ How did you make that conclusion? Are you running this in some sort of debugger? If so, it should be pretty easy to see if you're reading from the correct address.

Comment: The program is supposed to compare an array of 5 values that I declared as NUMB. It should compare store a 2 if the value is less than 10, a 0 if the value is between 10 and 100 and a 1 if the value is between 100 and 255.

Comment: I am using the simulated debugger in Keil. When it gets to the line to load the first value of the array it never does. It puts a value in that register r1 but it's not a value from the array. It then continues to execute the code. The additional register Im using r5 is just to keep a count and exit after the 5th array value has been compared.

Comment: What textbook are you using?

Comment: Embedded Systems With ARM Cortex-M3 Microcontrollers in Assembly Language and C

Comment: @PatWalsh - Ok you may not wish to invest in more books but ARM Assembly Language: Fundamentals and Techniques, Second Edition 2nd Edition, by William Hohl, Christopher Hinds is a good book that uses Keil and CCS examples.

Comment: I think the issue might be to do with the `LDR r0, =NUMB` Does r0 contain the address of the lsit of numbers after this instruction?

Comment: You are not advancing to the next elements within the array pointer. Your first LDR r1, [r0] instruction loads r1 with the first 4 byte element (i.e., 1); but so do the subsequent loops.

Comment: @InfinitelyManic So the command should read like LDR r1, [r0], #4 you are saying? I tried that also and it only gives me an error and will not allow debugging.

Comment: No... ldr r1, [r0, r5], where r5 is your element counter or index that increments by 4.  Element positions are at 0, 4, 8, 12...

Answer (score 0):

With respect to the array, your element size is not 1-byte, it's 4-bytes.

Using GNU & GDB, if we examine the address at R0 and interpret as signed words (i.e, 4 byte form), we see the expected array values.

```
.data
 NUMB:   .word 1,11,111,11,1
...
LDR r0, =NUMB
(gdb) x/8wd $r0
0x200dc:        1       11      111     11
0x200ec:        1       4929    1634033920      16804194
```

So you will need to change your values in the context of R5 to assume a 4-byte word. E.g.,

```
 CMP r5, #(4*5) 

 ADDS r5, #4
```

Answer (score 0):

Is is sadly very simple, just change in myData READWRITE to READONLY :)